# How to configure GooglePlacesAutocomplete API?

Tags: javascript, react-native, google-places-autocomplete

I got my Key from Google console developer Places API but when I try to use it in a react native app, 100% of the requisitions ocuurs an error.

[100% errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uQKDC.png)

```
 <GooglePlacesAutocomplete  style={styles.text}
            onPress={() => {} }
            query={{
                key:'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
                language: 'pt'

            }}
            textInputProps={{
                autoCapitalize : 'none',
                autoCorrect: false   
            }}
            fetchDetails
            enablePoweredByContainer= {false}

            />
```

How to get what causes the error? How to solve this?